# TCPDF only printing the last row

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

The following code only prints the last row, when I try to echo the table it's giving me all the rows but the pdf is only giving the last row. please help

```
$tbl1 = '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%" style="text-align:center;" border="1">
<tr style="font-weight:500;">
<td height="35">Deal Id</td>
<td>Deal Title</td>
<td>Deal Offer Id </td>
<td>No. Of Purchases</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Total Price</td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr>';
while($mwor_res1=mysql_fetch_array($mwor_qry5)){
    $tbl1.='<tr style="align="center">
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['deal_id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['title'].'</td>
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['deal_offer_id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['count( ord_dt.deal_offer_id )'].'</td>
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['sum( ord_dt.quantity )'].'</td>
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['sum( ord_dt.total_price )'].'</td>
    <td>'.$mwor_res1['order_date'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$tbl1.='</table>';

    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl1, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->Output('Deal-wise-report.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: It will be lots of lines but can you share echo output of `$tbl1` or did you already check if it is well-formatted? Maybe some of values coming from query is corrupting your `$tbl1` string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're setting the pointer to the last page before printing:

```
$pdf->lastPage();
```

The rest of your table might be on the first page.

You might want to either print all pages or adjust your page settings to make it fit on one page.

Comment: How can I set it to print all the pages, I am new to this tcpdf thing, Please help me.

Comment: what happens if you remove `$pdf->lastPage();` ?

Comment: It's giving the same result, only showing the last row.

Answer (score 0):

try using ob_start(), use this code

```
<?php
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    ob_start();
?>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%" style="text-align:center;" border="1">
    <tr style="font-weight:500;">
        <td height="35" align="center">Deal Id</td>
        <td align="center">Deal Title</td>
        <td align="center">Deal Offer Id </td>
        <td align="center">No. Of Purchases</td>
        <td align="center">Quantity</td>
        <td align="center">Total Price</td>
        <td align="center">Date</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    while($mwor_res1=mysql_fetch_array($mwor_qry5))
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['deal_id']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['title']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['deal_offer_id']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['count( ord_dt.deal_offer_id )']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['sum( ord_dt.quantity )']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['sum( ord_dt.total_price )']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $mwor_res1['order_date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
    $tbl1 = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl1, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('Deal-wise-report.pdf', 'D');
?>
```

Comment: i did some changes in above code, plz try now using above code

Comment: Pravin, thnx for your help.. I have to put the whole html in a php variable as I have shown in my code, when I am doing that with the code you have given it's giving me two blank pages.

Comment: I have used ob_start() with TCPDF in my number of projects and it is working fine for me. Please echo $tbl1 variable after ob_end_clean() and comment the last two lines (writeHTML() and output() function) and check what output you are getting.